# median of multiple files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several csv files that I'm loading into pandas. The contain all the same columns, and **almost** but not exactly the same indexes. The rows are indexed by a pair (segVar, val).

What I want is a new DataFrame in with the same columns, and the union of the indexes, and each row is the median of the appropriate rows from the other files.

I also need to keep the order of the rows the same. (The orders between the files will be consistent)

This is probably 2 questions: how best to get the union of the indexes, and how to get the medians. But if it can be done in one answer, that's great.

Comment: Can you post some sample data with desired output.

Comment: It seems like a job for concat + groupby but sample data and output would be nice.

Comment: yeah, I'm thinking that concat with groupby is the correct answer, My current sticking point is order. But it may be easiest to just concat, groupby median, and then re-order.

Comment: I think `combine_first` gives you union of indexes and then you can do `groupby`.

Comment: @ayhan, please make an answer of "concat and groupby" so that I can accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pd.concat to combine the DataFrames and use groupby on the index:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [2, 3, 5]}, index = [1, 2, 3])

df1
Out: 
   A  B
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  5

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 5, 2], 'B': [1, 6, 3]}, index = [2, 3, 5])

df2
Out: 
   A  B
2  4  1
3  5  6
5  2  3

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 3, 1], 'B': [3, 2, 5]}, index = [3, 4, 5])

df3
Out: 
   A  B
3  4  3
4  3  2
5  1  5
```

---

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby(level=0).median()
Out: 
     A    B
1  1.0  2.0
2  3.0  2.0
3  4.0  5.0
4  3.0  2.0
5  1.5  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as Ayhan says is concat and groupby. I'll post my next question (how to sort the rows) in a different question, because it is easier to phrase.